# Sort a contact list from my phone

Tags: java, android, sorting

I retrieve a list of my contacts from my phone, How can i sort them ?
i tried with adapter.sort but error can't resolve methode sort !

```
     listcontact = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.listcontact);

    Cursor cursor = getActivity().getContentResolver().query(
            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI
            ,new String[]{
            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone._ID,
            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME ,
            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER
            }
            ,null
            ,null
            ,null
    );

    getActivity().startManagingCursor(cursor);

    String[] from = new String[] {
            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME,
            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER
    };

    int[] to = new int[] { R.id.name, R.id.phone};

    SimpleCursorAdapter adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(getContext(), R.layout.listcontact, cursor, from, to);

    adapter.sort(new Comparator<String>() {
        @Override
        public int compare(String lhs, String rhs) {
            return lhs.compareTo(rhs);
        }
    });
    listcontact.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Comment: Asking without knowing Android development: what makes you think that a `SimpleCursorAdapter` should have a `sort` method?